# Cannot login to newly created user account

Tags: useradd, switch-user

Trying to switch accounts to my newly created account I get a black screen and then it takes me back to the main login screen after entering the correct password.

Upon logging into my previously existing account I get:

```
"System Program Problem Detected"

Details:

Executable path /usr/bin/Xorg

Package: xserver-xorg-core 2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10.1

Details: Crash
... (tons more, but no way to copy paste or save)
```

When I try to su

```
su -l penner
```

I get:

```
No directory, logging in with HOME=/
```

I manually created the home directory and this error goes away but still no luck with the login. Seems something has gone wrong with the user creation? How can I correct this?

Comment: How did you create the user account? Did you do it from the gui, or from command line? If you do it from command line, you need to be aware that adduser and useradd do things very differently. Also, it kinda seems like the files from /etc/skel weren't copied over. Could you please ls -al on your home dir and in the new user's dir so we can see what's going on?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you created the user account with [`useradd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/useradd.8.html), you have to set up everything for it manually. This is why, when creating user accounts from the command-line, it is recommended to use [`adduser`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/adduser.8.html) in Ubuntu (and Debian, and other Debian-based systems) instead. You might just want to remove the user with [`userdel`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/userdel.8.html) or [`deluser`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/deluser.8.html) and recreate it with `adduser`. Otherwise...

### Fixing the Home Directory Location

If you want to keep the user account and fix the problem, then you need to look at:

- the name of the home directory the user account is actually configured for
- the name of the directory you actually created

These must be exactly the same. The error message you get with `su -l penner` is telling you that they are not the same.

To check the home directory the user account is actually configured for, run this command (see [`man 5 passwd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/passwd.5.html) and [`man grep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/grep.1.html) for more information):

```
grep penner /etc/passwd
```

You should see a line like this:

```
penner:x:1000:1000:Eliah Kagan,,,:/home/penner:/bin/bash
```

That is, the sixth `:`-separated field (after the fifth `:`) contains the home directory. If it's not `/home/penner`, it should be. If the directory you created for the user is not `/home/penner`, it should be, too. If the two directories are the same but neither one is `/home/penner`, then that might theoretically work, but you should make them both `/home/penner`, because lots of software assumes that all non-`root` users' home directories are `/home/username`.

You can change `penner`'s home directory to `/home/penner` by running this command:

```
sudo usermod -d /home/penner penner
```

- See [`man usermod`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/usermod.8.html) for more information.

### Ensuring it is a Directory, and that the User Has Access

If (or once) the names are both `/home/penner`, you should also make sure that the user has access to their own home directory. Run:

```
ls -ld /home/penner
```

You should see something that looks like this (though the date and time will be different):

```
drwxr-xr-x 43 penner penner 4096 2012-07-03 06:41 /home/penner
```

If instead of `drwxr-xr-x`, you have something that starts with `-` rather than `d`, then you created a file rather than a directory. Delete the file and make a directory there instead.

If instead of the first `penner` you have something else, then the user doesn't own their home directory, so make them own it:

```
sudo chown penner /home/penner
```

- See [`man chown`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/chown.1.html) for more information.

If instead of `drwxr-xr-x` there are dashes in the next three characters after the `d`, then the user doesn't have full access there. Fix that as follows:

```
sudo chmod u+rwx /home/penner
```

- See [`man chmod`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/chmod.1.html) for more information.

(`penner` is capable of running this command if they own their home directory, so if you prefer, you can run this as: `sudo -u penner u+rwx /home/penner`)

### Ensuring Other Users Don't Have Blanket Write Access

If instead of `drwxr-xr-x`, there are `w`s instead of `-`s in the last six letters, then users besides `penner` may have write access to `penner`'s home directory. This is dangerous (unless you *really* know what you're doing and want it this way and have set things up so it won't be a problem). To fix it:

```
sudo chmod -R go-w /home/penner
```

### Other Defaults

There are some other changes you may want to make. **By default in Ubuntu** (that is, if you create a user account with `adduser` or with a graphical tool, which you did not):

1. [Home directories have read and write permissions for everyone, not just the user who owns them.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/Policies#Permissive_Home_Directory_Access) Users can change this, either for the whole home directory or any files and subdirectories inside it. But if you do want this default, and you don't have the second and third `r` and `x` in `drwxr-xr-x`, run:

   ```
   sudo chmod 755 /home/penner
   ```

   (`penner` is capable of running this command if they own their home directory, so if you prefer, you can run this as: `sudo -u penner chmod 755 /home/penner`)
2. Each user has his/her own group, with the same name as the user, and this is the user's primary group. Their home directory is owned by this group. That's the meaning of the second `penner` in `drwxr-xr-x 43 penner penner 4096 2012-07-03 06:41 /home/penner`. It's OK to break with this default, *if you know what you are doing*. But if it's not your intention to do things differently, you should make sure `penner` is set up this way, since some possible primary group identities for a user, or group owners on the user's home directory, could lead to security problems.

   Run `groups penner`. (See [`man groups`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/groups.1.html) for more information.) You should see something like this:

   ```
   penner : penner adm dialout cdrom plugdev lpadmin sambashare
   ```

   Don't worry if it's not quite like that. I'll get to that soon. Instead, look at the first word after the `:`. That's the name of the user's primary group. Assuming you want it to be `penner`, make sure it is. If it isn't, change it:

   ```
   sudo usermod -g penner penner
   ```

   If you get an error saying that the group `penner` doesn't exist, then you'll have to create it with this command (and then run the above command again):

   ```
   sudo addgroup penner
   ```

   - See [`man addgroup`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/addgroup.8.html) for more information. (If you prefer, you can alternatively use the [`groupadd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/groupadd.8.html) command to create groups.)
3. When you ran `groups penner`, you may have gotten a list of groups considerably shorter than my `penner : penner adm dialout cdrom plugdev lpadmin sambashare`. For desktop users, the `adm`, `dialout`, `cdrom`, `plugdev`, `lpadmin`, and `sambashare` provide abilities that desktop users should generally have. Therefore, unless you have a reason to do otherwise, `penner` should be in these groups. These are *not* primary groups, however, so they're set differently. Supposing `penner` is not in any of these groups and you want `penner` to be in all of them, run this command:

   ```
   sudo usermod -a -G adm,dialout,plugdev,lpadmin,sambashare penner
   ```

   In case you're interested, here's what all those groups mean:

   - `adm` users [can view](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Privileges#Monitor_system_logs) most system log files in `/var/log`.
   - `dialout` users [can use](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Privileges#Use_modems) dial-up modems.
   - `plugdev` users [can mount and use](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Privileges#Access_external_storage_devices) external storage devices.
   - `lpadmin` users [can set up and manage](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Privileges#Configure_printers) printers.
   - `sambashare` users [can share](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Privileges#Share_files_with_the_local_network) files (via [Samba](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man7/samba.7.html)) with other computers over a network.

   (Source: [Privileges](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Privileges), in the Ubuntu documentation wiki.)

### Making the User an Administrator

If you don't want `penner` to be an administrator, you probably don't need to do anything else. You can check if `penner` is an administrator with `groups penner`. If neither `admin` nor `sudo` is listed, then `penner` is not an administrator.

If you want `penner` to be an administrator, add `penner` to whichever of these groups exists. (You may as well add `penner` to both, if they both exist.) You can accomplish that by running these two commands separately--if either one succeeds, you've made `penner` an administrator:

```
sudo usermod -a -G admin penner
sudo usermod -a -G sudo penner
```

- The reason there are two groups is that, before Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, administrators were in the `admin` group. Starting with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, administrators are in the `sudo` group. But if your 12.04 LTS system is upgraded from a previous release (and this should apply to later Ubuntu releases, such as 12.10 when it comes out, that are upgraded from Ubuntu 11.10 or earlier), then for backward compatibility, administrators are members of both `sudo` and `admin`. Generally, if one of these groups doesn't confer administrative abilities, it simply doesn't exist, so running both the above two commands (separately, not as `sudo usermod -a -G admin,sudo penner`) is generally a safe and effective way to make `penner` an administrator.

Comment: Thanks! Something like adduser is nice but I like to know how to do things manually as well. A very thorough answer! I really appreciate it.

Comment: `sudo chmod u+a /home/penner` gives an error on Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial). Is `sudo chmod u+rw /home/penner` a proper replacement?

Comment: @NickolaiLeschov Sorry about that--and thanks for pointing out the error! I've fixed the command.

Comment: this is just dumb, why not remove `useradd` then? keeping random broken code

Comment: @EliahKagan `adduser ----no-create-home` will do. It seems it is not just setting up a home. `useradd` *may* leave things in a broken state on Ubuntu (there is also setting up shell or example). In Fedora useradd is fine.

Comment: @dashesy Thanks--I was not aware that using `useradd` causes problems on Ubuntu that it doesn't cause on other systems. On my 16.04 system, `/etc/default/useradd` has (as its only uncommented line) `SHELL=/bin/sh`, and useradd(8) seems to say that the `SHELL` value there is used if the `-s`/`--shell` flag isn't given, but on my 16.04 system that doesn't happen. I was wrong to say so hastily that Ubuntu's `useradd` isn't broken. Now I'm not so sure. Maybe there's a good reason for this difference between Fedora and Debian (and Ubuntu)... but I've deleted my comment so as not to mislead people.

Answer (score 2):

This mostly happens when you create the user without creating a home directory for the user. This can be solved by using this command when creating user

```
useradd -m the_username
```

The -m flag is what creates the home directory for the user. After creating the user check if the home directory exists for that user by doing

```
ls /home
```

If you can see that username listed there then the last thing to do is assign a password to that user

```
passwd the_username
```

You can now login with that username and password

Answer (score -1):

ctrl+alt+f1 and login there and run

sudo chown -R $USER:$USER $HOME

then press ctrl+alt+f7 and try to login

It will work